# Can I configure Hibernate/JPA to update an entity record when only non-timestamp fields have been modified?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

At the moment I have an Hibernate entity class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2040757598327793105L;

    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String data;    

    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModified;
}
```

I've found that even when the non-timestamp fields are not modified (i.e. the `data` field) a call to `merge` still updates the timestamp. I would like the timestamp to only update when other data fields have changed.

Is there anyway I can prevent calls to `merge` making a SQL `UPDATE` when all other data fields are not modified, or do I have to explicitly check for this myself in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Update (thanks to comment):

Since v4 of Hibernate `@Entity` annotation is deprecated and for allowing dynamic updates you should use `@DynamicUpdate(true)` (in conjunction with `@SelectBeforeUpdate(true)`)

---

If you want to prevent unmodified fields to be included in UPDATE queries, add this on your entity:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true) // update only changed fields
public class ...
```

Comment: Is there not a JPA property for this or do I have to use the hibernate version of the @Entity annotation?

Comment: you'd have to use both. No JPA standard AFAIK

Comment: Just wonder if there is a way I can configure Hibernate to globally enable dynamic update so that I don't have to use the Hibernate annotations.

Comment: Since v4 of Hibernate @Entity annotation is deprecated and for allowing dynamic updates you should use @DynamicUpdate(true)
(in conjunction with @SelectBeforeUpdate(true))